# CLASSIC: named set in MDX top 2 by dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, named

**SSAS 2012 Multidimensional** DW has

- Measures: Line total,
- Dimension with hierarchy: [Division] - [Sales
  Person].

I am trying to make set of top 2 salespersons by divisions. 
This code sample gives me the correct result in SSMS:

```
    with set [f] as 
     Generate(
       { [Sales Person].[Hierarchy].[All] . children }, 
            [Sales Person].[Division].CurrentMember *
                TopCount(
                EXISTING  [Sales Person].[Sales Person Id].children 
                        ,2 
                ,[Measures].[Line Total] 
                )
            ) 
            SELECT [Measures].[Line Total]  ON COLUMNS,
              [f]
   ON ROWS  from     [Adventure Works]
```

it's working fine. It will give me top 2 by division.
However, if i want to make named set in cube based on previous MDX thus:

```
 create dynamic set CURRENTCUBE.[f] as Generate(
       { [Sales Person].[Hierarchy].[All] . children }, 
            [Sales Person].[Division].CurrentMember *
                TopCount(
                EXISTING  [Sales Person].[Sales Person Id].children 
                        ,2 
                ,[Measures].[Line Total] 
                )
            )
```

it will give me no error but this named set **will not show** in the browser. Validation of the MDX code in the calculations tab passes ok.

Answer (score 0):

You say it won't show in the browser, have you allocated it a display folder? If not, it may not be where you expect to see it.

Can you use it in an MDX query OK?

Comment: MDX query works in SSMS. I cannot create named set even if i specify display folder. Code validates ok.

Comment: And you have processed the cube?

Comment: You've set display folder, have you set VISIBLE = 1? I can't remember the default behavior, so it might not be required, but it's worth a punt.